# Folders are hidden after scanning from Quickheal antivirus

Tags: virus, anti-virus

Today when I scanned my pendrive with Quickheal antivirus it detected some virus but it also made hide all folders. All the folders are present in that usb drive as it is showing the same file size from property but all the folders are hidden. So how to solve it?Any help and suggestions will be higly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

If your folders are hidden, you should be able to find them using "attrib" from the command line.

here is an example from my machine:

```
C:\>attrib
A  SHR       C:\IO.SYS
A  SHR       C:\MSDOS.SYS
A  SH        C:\pagefile.sys
A            C:\vcredist.bmp
```

The various flags mean:

```
R   Read-only file attribute.
A   Archive file attribute.
S   System file attribute.
H   Hidden file attribute.
```

It seems like there is a limitation using the attrib command, it does not show folders unless you recursively do it on the whole disk.

This is however done like this

```
attrib c:\* /s /d
```

And finally, to unhide everything on a disk (do not do this on your system partitions!)

```
attrib -s -h -r X:\* /d /s
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Folder Options, click on View tab, you will find an option "Hide protected operating system files". Uncheck it and click **Apply**, now your files will be visible. But it's better to copy them to a new folder after this.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 2000/XP users to see the Application Data folder, you will need to turn on the Show Hidden files and folder option.

```
Open My Computer.
From the Tools menu, click Folder Options, and then click the View tab.
Under Advanced Settings, click to select the Show hidden files and folders check box.
Click OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to run,and den type cmd.
command prompt will open.
find ur usb drive letter and type F:
den type attrib -s -h /s /d *.*
do check for the spaces between the command.
Just check the usb for files.MAGIC.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.